# UPDATE on a clustered COLUMNSTORE table with 150 columns and 30 mln records just stuck

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, columnstore

I have a table TABLE_A which is having 150 columns (with 5 lob type) and 30 millions. User were facing read performance issue, so I created CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE on the table. After I converted the table to COLUMSTORE read performance improved 5 time better.

BUT

There are some schedules that execute UPDATE on the table.

After I converted the table to COLUMNSTORE, UPDATE statement not even moving.

SQL Server optimizer reading all columns and rows from the table and index (in execution plan).

Here is the simple query.

```
UPDATE TBL SET COLUMN_5=TBL2.COLUMN_20 FROM TABLE_A TBL INNER JOIN TABLE_B TBL2 ON TBL.COL_ID=TBL2.COL_ID;
```

Thanks!

Comment: You would probably be better off doing a delete and insert, here. Updating column store indexes is a nightmare.

Comment: "UPDATE statement not even moving" test with a live query plan to ensure that it's an expensive query and not some sort of blocking.

Comment: i second what Erik Darling mentioned: UPDATE for clustered columnstore can be difficult to work with. Memory grants are critically important for modifications to clustered columnstores. DOP can be downgraded based on memory grant. and memory grant timeout can result in delta store inserts with minimal "required memory" - that can take forever.